# maximum of key value in rdd based operation in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I am new to rdd based operation. I am trying to understand max of a key-value. I have an rdd like this:

```
RDD = sc.parallelize([("A", 2, 1), ("C", 8, 5), ("B", 3, 4), ("A", 7, 5), ("C", 5, 8), ("C", 6, 10), ("B", 10, 6)])
```

I have to find the maximum of 2nd elements based on keys. I would like to see the output like this;

```
("A", 7, 5)
("B", 10, 6)
("C", 6, 10)
```

I tried `newrdd = RDD.reduceByKey(lambda x: max(x[2]))`. It output some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case if someone needed, I first got the paired rdd.

```
pairedrdd = RDD.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
```

then `newrdd = pairedrdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: max(x,y))`

```
lis = newrdd.collect()

for i in lis:
    print(i)
```